# How can I login oracle as sys account using oci or anyother libs

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface, sys

I am try to make a tool to help create user and imp database after oracle database installed.
Because it is too difficult for my colleagues to deployment a new database by typeing commands.
Then i tried using oci to login oracle sys account，but oci replay a mistake “ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified”,but a normal account is ok.Please tell me how can i connect oracle as sys.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle installation happens only once during deployment. So does importing of Database dumps. Why write a separate application to import/export DB dumps?

Sys account was not resolved from tnsnames.ora hence the ERROR.

You can:

1. Create normal user with sufficient privileges like

**[oracle@App ~]$  sqlplus "/ as sysdba"**

**CREATE USER user1 IDENTIFIED BY userpass DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;**

**GRANT CREATE SESSION, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, CREATE SYNONYM TO user1;**

1. Provide Import and Export script with necessary SQL statements.